# DynamoDB treats Number as Map in KeyConditionExpression -> fails

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

**Environment**

So I have the following QueryInput-Object in my TypeScript CDK project.

```
const params: QueryInput = {
    TableName: criticalMessagesTableName,
    ProjectionExpression: 'message',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'myId = :myId and #ts BETWEEN :startTimestamp AND :endTimestamp',

    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':myId': { S: myId },
        ':startTimestamp': { N: String(startTimestamp) },
        ':endTimestamp': { N: String(startTimestamp + range - 1) },
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#ts': 'timestamp',
    },
};
```

with the following variable values:

```
const myId = "some-string-based-partition-key-value";
const startTimestamp = 1630927923544; //ms since epoch value
const range = 60000; // some range in ms
```

The table has `myId` as partition key (String) and `timestamp` as sort key (Number).

**Problem**

When the query is executed with an AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient instance, the my error callback function writes the following log:

```
{
"message": "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: BETWEEN, operand type: M",
"code": "ValidationException",
"time": "2021-09-06T12:18:33.720Z",
"requestId": "M041V4RVD57IGRGNF7P7U15GRNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
"statusCode": 400,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 43.99195146574429
```

}

**I take from this that my :startTimestamp and :endTimestamp are somehow treated as a map. However I can't figure out why.**

Also just using <= and > as a workaround is not possible since you can only use one operator per key in a KeyConditionExpression.

Thanks for any help on this (TS specific) documentation on this is pretty minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`, and one of its main differences from its cousin, `AWS.DynamoDB`, is that it uses native JavaScript types instead of wrapping it in an `AttributeValue` map. So your query then should look like this:

```
const params: QueryInput = {
    // ...
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':myId': myId,
        ':startTimestamp': startTimestamp,
        ':endTimestamp': startTimestamp + range - 1,
    }
```

For more details, see the API docs for the document client here (especially the section "Marshalling Input and Unmarshalling Response Data"): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

Comment: Wow, VS Code autoimport loaded the wrong QueryInput-Type-Definition. Thanks a lot!